# Jquery Marquee Issue in iframe at initial loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I am facing an issue in marquee at initial iframe loading case the marquee class were built with the elements as like the following tag

```
<div id="marquee91" class="marquee marquee91" data-duplicated="true" data-direction="right" style="width:100px;height:82px;overflow:hidden;    display: inline-block;"><div style="width: 100000px; transform: translateX(0px); animation: 4.9995s linear 0s infinite normal none running marqueeAnimation-4921031;" class="js-marquee-wrapper"><div class="js-marquee" style="margin-right: 0px; float: left;"><img src="Images/Images/line1.png" style="object-fit:contain;"></div><div class="js-marquee" style="margin-right: 0px; float: left;"><img src="Images/Images/line1.png" style="object-fit:contain;"></div></div></div>
```

But the image is not moving (translate seems to be 0).If I move to other iframes its working fine.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#marquee' + test_id).marquee({
                direction: 'right',
                gap: 0,
                startVisible: true,
                delayBeforeStart: 0,
                duration: 9999
            });

        });
```

Kindly let me the issue I have did in this.
I have included the script files

```
             <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>

            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.js'></script>
```

Comment: You don't need to include both a `min.js` and a `.js` version of the same file.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks. I have removed the min.js but still the marquee is not moving at first iframe page load. Can you please suggest I have to change something else.